# Why does my script require int()?

Tags: python, string, shell, python-2.7, integer

I've created a basic function that work as a counter. However, for each argument that I pass through the script, the variable needs to be converted to an integer using int ().

Both variables in "fun_loop(n, b)" require int().

```
from sys import argv

script, max_number, increment = argv 

def fun_loop(n, b):

    i = 0
    numbers = []

    while i < int(n):
        print "At the top i is %d" % i
        numbers.append(i)

        i = i + int(b)
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        print "At the bottom i is %d" % i


    print "The numbers: "

    for num in numbers:
        print num

print "We can just give the numbers directly"
fun_loop(6, 1)

print "Or we can use variables from our script"
fun_loop(max_number, increment)
```

If I run the code without int() on the variables then I either get...

an infinite loop - if I pass variable `n` without `int()`

or

`TypeError: unsupported operand` - if I pass variable `b` without `int()`.

How can I make this script work without having to use `int()` when passing each variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the elements of the `sys.argv` list are all strings, always.

You could just convert those to integers *before* passing them into the function:

```
max_number, increment = map(int, argv[1:])
fun_loop(max_number, increment)
```

Specifically, you get an infinite loop because integers sort before everything else in Python 2:

```
>>> 1 < '1'
True
```

and you get your `TypeError` because using `+` on an integer and a string is not a valid operation in Python:

```
>>> 0 + '1'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: I ran the code by converting the arguments into integers before, as your code posted. However I run into this error.   

`File "ex33s.py", line 5, in <module>
    script, max_number, increment = map(int, argv[1:])
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack`

My code is as follows 

`script, max_number, increment = map(int, argv[1:])

def fun_loop(n, b):`

Comment: @user3200293: look closely at the code I gave you. I am **not** assigning to `script, max_number, increment`. I left out `script` because the script name does not need to be converted to an integer.

Comment: Yes, once you put formatting on your comment I saw why you get the error.